# JavaFX Maven Plugin: com.zenjava - How to copy external resources

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-plugin

I'm relatively new to Maven + JavaFX and I'm trying to produce a JavaFX executable jar file with the com.zenjava maven plugin.

I was following this guide for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbjW8rYlook

I have the following folder structure for my project:
[image]

Now I'm trying to run the config `jfx:jar` during maven build and was able to produce a jar file but the resources I need are not copied under the `target/jfx/app` folder.

[image]

Basically, I want to copy the entire `src/main/resources` folder to `target/jfx/app/resources`. How do I accomplish this?

Some information:
The `src/main/resources/` folder will contain different kinds of files that I will need during runtime, (excel files, pdf, htmls...) and not just property files.

Thanks in advance.

========================================================================
**UPDATE:**
Yuri-M-Dias' answer helped.

Without changing any other setting, I managed to do this by just updating my pom file with:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>../jfx/app/resources</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>



    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>me.iamkenos.bayonetta.MainApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is definitely working but I'm not sure whether this is the best way, given I had to cheat it a bit by using "`../`" in `<targetPath>../jfx/app/resources</targetPath>` will wait for other possible answers for the meantime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control Maven's output folders to specific folders using the `resources` keyword. For example, on my project:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java/view</directory>
            <targetPath>view</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I am forcing the contents of the `java/view` folder to output to the `target/classes/view` in this case, since it's where my JavaFX images and fxmls are. You can probably do the same for the `jfx/app/resources` folder.

As for copying the folder, you can take a look at the [official maven recommendation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I got it to work but I'm not sure whether what I did was the best possible solution I can do. (See update on my question). 

I will wait for further possible answers before accepting this one. 

As for the link given, I was actually looking at this one earlier but I'm unable to understand most of the content of `maven-resources-plugin` like id, phase, configuration. I wish they'd put more explanations on that link to help freshers out.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

When you run the command `jfx:jar` you will get executable [jar file with resources folder inside](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/215#issuecomment-230323210) because you added resources folder to the build path.

If you just copy the entire `src/main/resources` folder to `target/jfx/app/resources` folder you will have copies of the same resource files (inside and outside of generated jar file) and if you need to allow a user to edit some of resource files (e.g. `*.properties` files) your code I guess will rely on the inside files so user changes have no any effect in this case.

That is why you need to split project resources into:

- Internal (the part of generated jar file e.g. raster graphics and read-only configs)
- External (located outside the jar file e.g. config files that could be edited by user)

I would suggest to create 3 folders

- `\src\main\java` (source code) - part of a build path
- `\src\main\resources` (internal) - part of the build path
- `\src\main\config` (external)- excluded from the build path

use maven to copy external config folder and build executable jfx jar

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
            <targetPath>../jfx/app/config</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.8.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <vendor>${vendor}</vendor>
            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
            <allPermissions>true</allPermissions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The finishing touch is configuring [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) path to allow eclipse work in debug mode properly with external resources. You can use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to do it.

for Windows it might look like

```
mklink /J C:\...\target\classes C:\...\target\jfx\app\config
LinkToFolder                    OriginalFolder
```

`LinkToFolder` is eclipse project folder with compiled classes